# PayPal does not want to use PayPal balance, but forces to use credit card

Tags: paypal

I am sending money to family and want to use my PayPal balance as it charges a 1% fee. However, each time I try to send it, PayPal offers credit card which has a much larger fee.

I read that PayPal balance is always preferred, but PayPal does not use it.

Why is this happening? How can I force PayPal to use money from PayPal balance instead of my credit card?

Further information: I am sending from European but non-EU country to an EU country. The balance is at least 5 times larger than the one I have to send. And funds were added yesterday. I thought about it and waited today, but the situation is still the same. If I choose "send money" it only offers to use the credit card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is intentional. Rule for some countries. Some countries will not be allowed to use existing Skype credit, but all money is sent to the credit card and then you use it to pay another bill.